# How to write a text file to a desktop sub-folder in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Please I want to write a text file to a sub-folder I have created within a folder on the desktop i.e.

Desktop Folder > Sub-folder > Text file

The code I came up with is shown below. I have created the sub-folder within the parent desktop folder, but cannot locate this sub-folder to write and save the text file. Please I would appreciate any suggestions. I am using Visual Basic 2010 Express. Thank you in advance.

```html
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

‘Check if a sub-folder with the title specified in Textbox1 does not exist in desktop folder      titled Family

        If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Desktop\Family\" & TextBox1.Text)) Then

   ‘Create a sub-folder within desktop folder titled Family with the title specified in Textbox1

         System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Desktop\Family\" & TextBox1.Text)
        End If

Dim fileTXT As New IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Desktop\Family\" & TextBox1.Text & TextBox1.Text & ".TXT")

        fileTXT.Write(TextBox2.Text)
        fileTXT.WriteLine("")
        Close()

    End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use `"C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Desktop\"` to create a desktop path. There is no guarantee that that's where the desktop is. It has changed with various versions of Windows and you have the option to manually move the desktop to another folder. Mine is on "D" drive.

Comment: @Kairan It is vb.net. Enigmativity has given me valuable advice. Now, the problem I am having is writing multiple lines of text separated by spaces to the text file. Do you have any ideas, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write your code this way:

```
    Dim di = New DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine( _
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), _
            "Family\" & TextBox1.Text))
    If Not di.Exists
        di.Create()
    End If
    Dim fn = Path.Combine(di.FullName, TextBox1.Text + ".TXT")
    File.WriteAllText(fn, TextBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine)
```

Comment: @ Enigmativity: Many thanks. Your suggested snippet works like a charm! Also, your suggestion about not using "C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Desktop\" makes sense. I have adopted your idea. Thanks again.

Comment: @ Enigmativity: One more little question please, your code writes the text from the textbox to file which is fine. But how do I add empty line spaces beneath this first line of text; then write other lines of text and so on?Thank you in advance.

Comment: @lki - Try `File.AppendAllLines(...)`. Also, don't put a space after the "@:" when tagging someone as it then doesn't send a notification.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but adding multiple lines of text, separated by spaces now seems to be the problem. Please would you have any other ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Iki - Can you let me know what "separated by spaces now seems to be the problem" means?

Comment: Thank you for replying to me. What I mean is that I can't add another line of text or space beneath the first line of text in the text file.

Comment: @Iki - Did you try `File.AppendAllText(...)`?

Comment: This is what I am using and the result is that the code writes only “Second line of text”. I would like to write;
First line of text
[space]
Second line of text
And so forth…

Dim fn = Path.Combine(di.FullName, TextBox1.Text + ".TXT")
        File.WriteAllText(fn, "First line of text" + Environment.NewLine)
        File.AppendAllText(fn, "" + Environment.NewLine) ‘Space
        File.WriteAllText(fn, "Second line of text” + Environment.NewLine)

Comment: @Iki - The second `WriteAllText` is completely overwriting the file. You only use `AppendAllText` after the file has been created.

Comment: Very well.I am so sorry for taking so much of your time but I am relatively new to vb.net and can't still get it to work. Could you please write a code to demonstrate how I can to get the code to write multiple lines of codes separated by spaces?

Comment: @Iki - I don't mind helping out, but I think you've now asked a question that I can't answer in a comment. Please put your code together and ask a new question here on SO. Once you do, please paste a link to the question in these comments and I'll have a go at answering it for you.

Comment: @Iki - And please get into the habit of using the "@" notifications in your comments.

Comment: Success! I finally figured it out. What eventually worked for me is:

Dim filename As String = Path.Combine(di.FullName, TextBox1.Text + ".TXT")
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(filename)
        objWriter.Write(TextBox1.Text)
        objWriter.WriteLine("")
        objWriter.Write(TextBox2.Text)

Thanks for your advice!!!!!

Comment: @Iki - Please make sure that you call `.Dispose()` on your `StreamWriter` when you're done writing to it.

Comment: @Iki - And how `StreamWriter` helps you better than `File.AppendAllText(...)` I don't know.

Comment: @Iki - You would use it exactly the same as your `StreamWriter` example.

Comment: I am using the “@” symbol but when I add the comments; they simply disappear. Well, I would very happily adopt your suggestion if you have a better suggestion, dear friend. I have found your suggestions very helpful. I would gladly use the File.AppendAllText(...) if you could tell me how to actually use it to write multiple lines of text with spaces between them in the created text file.

Comment: @Iki - Try this `File.AppendAllText(path, TextBox1.Text + " " + TextBox2.Text);`.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far but the code you have just suggested writes the contents of the texbox 2 along the same line as the content of textbox 1. What I was targeting was to write the second line of text beneath the first line of text with a space between these two lines.

Comment: @Iki - Sorry, I misunderstood. Try this: `File.AppendAllText(path, String.Join(Environment.NewLine, new [] { TextBox1.Text, "", TextBox2.Text }));`

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get the desktop folder:

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)`

You can then use `System.IO.Path.Combine` to add the Family subfolder. Make sure that subfolder exists before creating any folders underneath it.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Pleas would you happen to know how I can add multiple lines of text, separated by blank line spaces to the text file?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Pleas would you happen to know how I can add multiple lines of text, separated by blank line spaces to the text file?

Comment: What is the source of the text? textbox2.text? Is this a multi-line textbox?

Comment: The source of the text varies. For some lines, the source is a textbox; for other lines, it is text I insert when writing the code e.g "Family Report 2015" etc. In the end, what I would like is a text file with multiple vertical lines and spaces separating those lines. What I am getting now is that the code only writes the last line of text in my vertical list of codes and does not write the preceding lines of code. Thank you in advance.